# Request voltando Decimal

Tags: laravel-5

Pessoal tenho um campo num form que é tipo text e quando eu dou um post no formulario e capituro o request->get este campo volta string quando tem alguma letra nele. mas se so contiver numeros ele retorno no reqeust->get como decimal.

Como eu faço para ele sempre retornar string mesmo quando for somente numero?

```
 {!! Form::text('background', NULL, ['class'=>'form-control', 'maxlength'=>'6', 'id' => 'background']) !!}
```

Se eu preencho com por exemplo 007788 o dd($request->get('background')); volta como 7788.00 ai se eu coloco a07788 o dd($request->get('background')); retorna a07788

Obrigado

Comment: Pessoal olha sobre esta minha dúvida é alguma coisa na biblioteca Request do Laravel 5.1. Fiz um teste colocando dd($_POST['background']) e para a minha surpresa a resposta foi uma string com 007788. Então a classe Request esta transformando em numero de vez manter a string. Alguém sabe como tirar isto?

Answer (score 0):

Faça o cast para o tipo que você quer:

- String

  `dd((string) $request->get('background'))`
- Integer

  `dd((int) $request->get('background'));`